# Connecting 32-bit R to a 32-bit Access database

Tags: r, ms-access, rodbc

I am using 32-bit `R` with RStudio to try and connect to an `.accdb` file.  I have 32-bit MS Access running on my machine.

R version:

```
platform       i386-w64-mingw32            
arch           i386                        
os             mingw32                     
system         i386, mingw32               
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.2                         
...
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
nickname       Pumpkin Helmet
```

I'm trying to use the `RODBC` package to connect to an MS Access database. I cannot use `odbcConnectAccess("location_of_database.accdb")` to connect to a database provided by a client.  This particular database was created with Access 2013.  When I try to connect, I get a variety of warning messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state HY000, code -1028, message [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft     Access Driver] Cannot open database '(unknown)'.  It may not be a database that     your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.
2: closing unused RODBC handle 12 
3: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 1, message [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General Warning Unable to open registry key 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0x11a4 Thread 0x798 DBC 0x88e0064 Jet'.
4: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 1, message [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General Warning Unable to open registry key 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0x11a4 Thread 0x798 DBC 0x88e0064 Jet'.
5: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) : ODBC connection failed
```

Interestingly, I can use `odbcConnectAccess2007()` to connect successfully to databases that were created with *Access 2010*; however, when I try to use `odbcConnectAccess()` to connect to those same databases, I get the same errors above.

A Google search of the `Error: state 01000, code 1` message above suggests that [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/295297) may be helpful, but even after following the steps to alter the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` does not work.

While I originally thought [that this question was promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244425/general-error-unable-to-open-registry-key-temporary-volatile-from-access), the warning message there relates to "ACE DSN" while the error messages I'm seeing relate to "Jet DSN."

I cannot open the databases I'm trying to access with `RODBC` with my version of Access as the databases were created with Access 2013 and I have Access 2010 installed.

Can anyone help me trouble shoot why I can't open this database with `odbcConnectAccess()`?

Comment: Have you tried opening the Access_2013 database using your copy of Access_2010? What happens when you do? Also have you tried opening that database in R using `odbcConnectAccess2007()` instead of `odbcConnectAccess()`?

Comment: I get an error message that says `"Unrecognized database format [database location.accdb]."`

Comment: Have you tried opening that database in R using `odbcConnectAccess2007()` instead of `odbcConnectAccess()`?

Comment: Yes.  I get the same errors as in my original question.

Comment: There is fundamentally no difference between Access 2007-2016 files as they all use same format. Certain UI features may differ even table elements but R connects to the ACE engine and not GUI. The *unrecognized database format* suggests corruption. Try creating a new Access .accdb and import all objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why I can't open this [Access 2013] database with `odbcConnectAccess()`?

I'm fairly certain that

```
odbcConnectAccess(<fileSpec>)
```

is simply shorthand for

```
odbcDriverConnect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=<fileSpec>')
```

(i.e., the older "Jet" ODBC driver), and

```
odbcConnectAccess2007(<fileSpec>)
```

is simply shorthand for

```
odbcDriverConnect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=<fileSpec>')
```

(i.e., the newer "ACE" ODBC driver).

The older "Jet" driver cannot work with .accdb files, so `odbcConnectAccess2007()` would be required. If that throws an "Unrecognized database format" error then it's likely that the database file is damaged.