# Access 2013 database read in R through RODBC

Tags: r, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2013, rodbc

I am trying to open an access database in R using RODBC but I've been unable to do so.

Based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070706/how-to-connect-r-with-access-database-in-64-bit-window), I've converted the R version being used in Rstudio to 32 bit instead of 64 bit.

I have also tried using the language in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146494/connecting-32-bit-r-to-a-32-bit-access-database/37148596?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) post:

```
odbcDriverConnect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=<fileSpec>')
```

I have also looked over possible reasons in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244425/general-error-unable-to-open-registry-key-temporary-volatile-from-access?noredirect=1&lq=1) as to why the connection is not being established.

The files are not locked and I have changed my R version to a 32 bit to match the ODBC drivers 32 bit. I am also able to establish odbc connection to the access driver using STATA, so I don't think I have any permission problems.

When listing the available data sources, I get the following showing the driver I'm trying to access:

```
> odbcDataSources()
                                             Excel Files 
"Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)" 
                                      MS Access Database 
              "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)"
```

When trying to just connect to the Access Data Source, I get the following error:

```
ch <- odbcConnect("MS Access Database")
Warning messages:
1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=MS Access Database") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLDriverConnect
2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=MS Access Database") :
  ODBC connection failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access is a file-level DBMS. Hence, you need to specify the location of your database. The default *MS Access Database* DSN alone will not suffice. Without specifying the file, your error is reproduced.

```
conn <- odbcConnect("MS Access Database;DBQ=C:\\Path\\To\\Database.accdb")
df <- sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM myTable")
odbcClose(conn)
```

Now if you did create your own user-defined DSN with the .mdb/.accdb file specified, you certainly can connect with it alone.

```
conn <- odbcConnect("myDSN")
df <- sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM myTable")
odbcClose(conn)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
library(RODBC)

# for 32 bit windows
# Connect to Access db
# channel <- odbcConnectAccess("C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/Coding/Microsoft Access/Northwind.mdb")

# Get data
# data <- sqlQuery( channel , paste ("select * from Name_of_table_in_my_database"))


# for 64 bit windows
channel <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:/Users/Excel/Desktop/Coding/Microsoft Access/Northwind.mdb")

data <- sqlQuery( channel , paste ("select * from CUSTOMERS"))

odbcCloseAll()
```