# NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:access.pyodbc

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-access

I want to import a dataframe into a access database but I got an error `NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:access.pyodbc`

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib
import pyodbc

conec = (r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
         r"DBQ=C:\Users\redim\Desktop\18_marzo\Libr2.accdb"
        )
    
con = f"access+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(conec)}"
acc_engine = create_engine(con)
df.to_sql('hola', acc_engine)
```

Comment: Have you installed sqlalchemy-access? `pip install sqlalchemy-access`

Comment: Yes rfkortekaas, if you have other way to make it, I would appreciate it

Comment: Have a look at the [wiki](https://github.com/gordthompson/sqlalchemy-access/wiki/Getting-Connected). It looks like your connection string is missing a slash. Also there is a space between the comma and * in the Driver name!

Comment: I just did it but it doesn't work

Comment: Does `pip list|findstr access` return anything?

Comment: returns me  sqlalchemy-access                  1.0.8

Comment: @BlessingBribiesca - At the beginning of your app, add`import sqlalchemy_access as sa_a`. Does it throw an `ImportError`?

Comment: @GordThompson I have a new error:  ('HY000', "[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0xfa8 Thread 0x2cc0 DBC 0x17707914                                                              Jet'. (63) (SQLDriverConnect); [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0xfa8 Thread 0x2cc0 DBC 0x17707914                                                              Jet'. (63);

Comment: [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Cannot open database '(unknown)'. It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt. (-1028)")

Comment: @BlessingBribiesca - See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26244425/2144390) for information on that error message.

Comment: @GordThompson thank you, it help me but now my databse is in blank and weigth 3,140 KB and my code dont stop run, I guess that I need to find another way to solve it

Comment: @BlessingBribiesca - You could try making a copy of the .accdb (for safety) and then open it in the Access UI and do a "Compact and Repair Database" operation on it.

Comment: @GordThompson - I'm having this exact same error.  
When I run the pip list|findstr access I get an error 
'C:\Users\Patrick' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 
This is likely due to a space being in the file path.

Answer (score -1):

For some reason this only works in Jupyter notebooks, not in PyCharm which I was having the same problems for quite some time in both until I upgraded SQLalchemy

I use conda install with most of my libraries:

```
conda update sqlalchemy
```

But if you are using pip, then below is command:

```
pip install --upgrade sqlalchemy
```

I went from sqlalchemy 1.3.7 to 1.4.39 and the error went away, at least in Jupyter Notebooks anyways.