# Tkinter to Connect to MS Access Database

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm trying to make a GUI using tkinter to select the MS Access Database. I get an error: "General error Unable to open registry key Temporary (volatile) Ace DSN for process 0xcb8 Thread 0x39b8 DBC 0x1d234678" pointing to the connection line. Why doesn't this work.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
import os
 
# Create an instance of tkinter frame
win = Tk()

# Set the geometry of tkinter frame
win.geometry("700x350")

def open_file():
   file = filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('MS Access File', '*.accdb')])
   if file:
      filepath = os.path.abspath(file.name)
      Label(win, text="The File is located at : " + str(filepath), font=('Aerial 11')).pack()
      conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ = ' + filepath)
      qry=("select * from Table1")
      dataf = pd.read_sql(qry, conn)
      conn.close()      

# Add a Label widget
label = Label(win, text="Browse for file", font=('Georgia 13'))
label.pack(pady=10)

# Create a Button
ttk.Button(win, text="Browse", command=open_file).pack(pady=20)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with tkinter. You would get the same error with or without tkinter.

Comment: Your problem is not related to tkinter.
I hope this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26244425/general-error-unable-to-open-registry-key-temporary-volatile-from-access